# Variable field name / attribute name from string dynamic variable in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

In my angular 5 app that I am working on I retrieve, from dynamodDB, a json that looks like something like this (it is retrived as an array and used with `*ngFor`, but for the simplisity for this question I can say it is  stored like this in the component":

```
public person = {
  "userID" : "abc123...",
  ...
  "period1_status" : "applied",
  "period2_status" : "placed",
  "period3_status" : "applied",
  ...
}
```

In my component I have a variable string, named chosenPeriod, which I can change with a `<select>` tag. It is changed to `'period1'`, `'period2'` or `'period3'`.

```
public chosenPeriod = 'period2'
```

And in other parts in the html for the component I have a `<mat-chip>` (using material2) which I only want to show if `periodX_status` equals to `'applied'`, where X is the value of `chosenPeriod`. Somthing like this:

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="person.chosenPeriod+'_status' == 'applied'"><mat-icon>drag_handle</mat-icon></mat-chip>
```

where I want it to be `*ngIf="person.period1_status == 'applied'` if `chosenPeriod = 'period1'` etc.

The example above doesn't of course work. But is there a way in angular5 / HTML to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [object property accessors/bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), as follows:

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="person[chosenPeriod + '_status'] == 'applied'">
```

In the example above, if `chosenPeriod` was `'period1'`, it would be the same as:

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="person['period1' + '_status'] == 'applied'">
```

Which is the same as:

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="person['period1_status'] == 'applied'">
```

What, in the end, has the same effect of:

```
<mat-chip *ngIf="person.period1_status == 'applied'">
```

Comment: If it elicited a 'wow', I'd recommend an upvote in addition to marking as excepted.

Comment: @Engam Ah, I see.